# Qt integration in major operating system to interact with contact book

Tags: windows, macos, qt, app-store, contacts

I have a really big project that will use for example mails, contacts and other native integration stuffs in the systems ( windows, mac and linux).

Before begin the project I have to be sure that the frameworks I'll use can interact with those systems. I'm planning to use Qt because it's cross-platform ( and I'm familiar with it ).

My questions is :

- Can Qt add for example contact to mac ox s and windows ( or linux )?
  If not, can you give me an alternative to use ( I think about MONO but I'm not good in .net )
- With C++, my app can access to mac appstore and windows market?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cross-platform Qt interfaces for accessing mail, contacts, ... on desktop (there is Qt Mobility for mobile).

You'd have to use native c++ libraries for that.

Comment: ok thank you ill try to find some libraries to do this, and ill give the a feeddBack.